# write C plugin using some script language

Tags: c, plugins, proxy

I have API which loads custom C dll as plugin.

What I want is create some proxy dll which will:

- Transfer calls from application core
  to some script.
- Transfer callbacks from that script
  back to application core.

The API is quite complex, so it will be much work to wrap everything manually - is there anything which will automate that? (Any script language should work, e.g. lua, tcl, perl).

Basically I need something like tolua, but it will allow to just invoke callbacks. More interesting to generate lua-stubs which will be automatically called from core application (via proxy plugin?). (And these stubs should be generated basing on plugin C API).

Anybody knows which tool can be used for that?

Answer (score 1):

The 'standard' way to do this is to write your interop functions in some interface definition language and write a parser for that language to spit out the C/lua/etc. code that you want (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Have you heard of swig? (http://www.swig.org/), that may help.

The method we use internally is to skip the IDL step and mark our C code up directly with things we want exported. e.g. 
AUTO_PARSE JSON_RPC;
void foo(char *name, int age)
{
//...
}

in a pre-process step we scan source files for AUTO_PARSE tags and spit out special .c files that we compile in with the information for, e.g., json rpc.

Hope this helps!
Aaron

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. But Should I write own parser and IDL compiler? I was hoping to hear about some tools which will do the job for me, but looks there isn't any fully ready for public use jet.

Comment: we've open sourced HPHP now, and it has a pretty simple plugin architecture if you want to copy that, check out /src/idl